# Difference between header-bar and class=bar-header

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

There are two ways in which one can make headers using Ionic framework.

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

And

```
<header-bar title="'Title'" type="bar-dark">
 </header-bar>
```

Links in Documentation :
For first : http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/
For second : http://ionicframework.com/docs/angularjs/views/header/

What is the difference between them?

Comment: See similar question response here : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-vs-div-directives/7524/4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is native HTML elements using the predefined CSS class names.

The second is using an AngularJS directive. Basically it is a custom element that at runtime will be replaced by a template. See [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-angular-cordova-seed/blob/master/www/lib/js/ionic-angular.js#L1163) for the actual AngularJS directive definition. You can see the template that replaces the original element.

Directives like this will play an interesting part of the future of the web. There is a standard on its way in [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) that will standardize these kind of markup constructs. Besides directives in AngularJS there is another popular way of doing this style of components using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks. So I have another query now, which one should be used? If the custom element is being replaced by a template at runtime, will it have any performance issues?

Comment: There is a bit of overhead but changes to the directive are made in one place only. It is a trade off between performance and reusability.  I would go for the directive if there is a lot of reuse or it makes your markup easier to read.